# dataframe error when I didn't create any dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to detect the sentiment of the linked news, when I run

```
my_url <- "https://www.voanews.com/covid-19-pandemic/russia-begins-covid-inoculations"

description <- read_html(my_url) %>% 
  html_nodes('p') %>% html_text() %>% toString()

detect_sentiment(description)
```

It has error, saying

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
In addition: Warning message:
In comprehendHTTP(action = "DetectSentiment", body = bod, ...) :
  Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

what can be the problem? I realized that "dataframe" is the value of detect_sentiment function. And when I traceback(), it says:

```
> traceback()
5: stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
       paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
4: data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)
3: cbind(deparse.level, ...)
2: cbind(Index = 0, Sentiment = out$Sentiment, flatten(out$SentimentScore), 
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
1: detect_sentiment(description)
```

I tried another link and it worked well:

```
my_url2 <- "https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-55199551"
  
  description2 <- read_html(my_url2) %>% 
    html_nodes('.e5tfeyi2 p') %>% html_text() %>% toString()
  
  df1 <- data.frame(detect_sentiment(description2))
```

My packages are:

```
library("aws.comprehend")
library(rvest)
library("aws.translate")
library("aws.polly")
library("tuneR") 
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library('dplyr')
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are using `xml2`, `rvest`, `aws.comprehend`, and either `magrittr` or `dplyr`? (Please state non-base packages.)

Comment: It's working fine for me.Not sure what the problem is, as mentioned in the comments , please specify libraries included

Comment: My guess is that `comprehendHTTP` is returning something unexpected. I suggest you `debug(detect_sentiment)`, run through the [assignment to `out`](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.comprehend/blob/master/R/detect_sentiment.R#L25) (or [#32](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.comprehend/blob/master/R/detect_sentiment.R#L32)), and look at `out` to see what is seemingly wrong about it.

Comment: Since @PKumar isn't having the same problem, that (to me) suggests it's either a transient network problem (reattempt and it might work) or some problem with the AWS account credentials.

Comment: thank you all! it turns out that there was too much text (exceeding 5000) and the service stopped! I cut the text to less than 5000 and it worked.